# Uniform convergence for uniformly bounded, monotonic sequence of continuous functions over a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a uniformly bounded sequence of continuous functions such that $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x \in X$ where $X$ is compact.  Prove $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to some function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$.

For starters, we can use monotonicity and the uniformly boundedness to show point-wise convergence.  By Dini's theorem, the convergence is uniform if and only if $f$ is continuous.  I'm having some trouble showing that the convergence is uniform or that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: What about $f_n(x) = x^{1/n}$ on the space $X = [0,1]$?

Comment: That really does seem like a counter example, doesn't it.  I pulled the question from a comprehensive exam so I forgot to actually look for one.

Comment: Yeah, the convergence definitely isn't uniform, and nor is your limit function continuous.